# Script Canvas2Image não funciona no Chome

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Boa tarde a todos,

Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de assinaturas de e-mail aqui para o serviço.
Peguei um script pronto que utiliza o 'html2canvas' e o 'canvas2image' para transformar o código em imagem e posteriormente, possibilitar que o usuário salve a imagem como .png.
Porém,quando clico no botão "Salvar Assinatura" aparece um exemplo da assinatura em baixo que a pessoa pode selecionar 'Salvar como.." mas o Logotipo da empresa,que está na pasta do projeto no formato .png não aparece no resultado final.

O código JS que estou utilizando é esse

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#gerador"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            //Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);

        }

    });
  });
});
```

Eu sei que esse script realiza o download do arquivo,porém o mesmo está vindo sem nenhuma extensão,não sei o motivo disso.

Agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Cade o codigo do download?

Comment: Estava comentado,é esse aqui Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);

Comment: Dei uma olhada aqui no Stack e resolvi o problema de salvar sem formato,era necessário editar o script canvas2image.js .
Um problema eu resolvi,agora falta fazer funcionar no Chrome,no Mozilla funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: manda o link do download desse codigo pronto

Comment: Qual código está se referindo?Se for esse que coloquei acima,eu achei ele na internet enquanto procurava uma solução para meu problema.

Comment: Alguma luz @RafaelAugusto ?

Comment: Deve ser problema do CORs, dê detalhes por favor. Pode ser até problema no CSS

Comment: O CSS está bem simples,nada que possa remover a logo do resultado final.

Comment: Problema resolvido.

Comment: @OtávioCapila se o problema foi resolvido, por favor, adicione a solução como resposta.

Comment: Não sei a causa do problema,mas depois que subi a página para produção no servidor,o script funcionou normalmente em todos os navegadores.